# SDL2 - how to get the appropriate display resolution

Tags: sdl-2

I'm trying to open a fullscreen window using SDL2. I've thoroughly looked at the documentation on Display and window management ( https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryVideo )... however I don't understand what the best practice would be to get the display resolution I am actually working on.

I have the following sample code:

```
SDL_DisplayMode mMode;
SDL_Rect mRect;

int ret0 = SDL_GetDisplayBounds(0, &mRect);
std::cout << "bounds w and h are: " << mRect.w << " x " << mRect.h << std::endl;
int ret2 = SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode(0, &mMode);
std::cout << "current display res w and h are: " << mMode.w << " x " << mMode.h << std::endl;
int ret3 = SDL_GetDisplayMode(0, 0, &mMode);
std::cout << "display mode res w and h are: " << mMode.w << " x " << mMode.h << std::endl;
```

I am working on a single display that has a resolution of 1920x1080. However, the printed results are:

[program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgWKx.png)

It seems that SDL_GetDisplayMode() is the only function that displays the correct resolution, so I'd be inclined to use that one. However, I've read that when it comes to SDL_GetDisplayMode(), display modes are sorted according to a certain priority, so that calling it with a 0 returns the largest supported resolution for the display, which is not necessarily the actual resolution (see also: [SDL desktop resolution detection in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37722003/sdl-desktop-resolution-detection-in-linux) ).

My question is: what is the best practice to obtain the correct resolution?

Comment: I'd use this command: `SDL_GetDisplayBounds(SDL_GetWindowDisplayIndex(window), ...);`. Does it give correct resolution on your system?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I get the same 1280x720 that way... but of course I am only able to call it after the window has been created, which means I would then have to resize the window if the resolution is not ok (that's a small price I could pay...)

Comment: Calling this works: SDL_GetDisplayMode(0,SDL_GetWindowDisplayIndex(window), &mMode)... but I still don't know if this will always yield correct results or if it returns some kind of theoretical maximum as I said in the post...

Comment: There is one more function to try: `SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode()`. If it won't work properly, then I'd check again if your display resolution is indeed set to 1920x1980.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work properly. Only SDL_GetDisplayMode works properly, with that caveat. My resolution is indeed set to 1920x1080... :S

Comment: That's weird. What system you're on? Exactly what SDL version?

Comment: What's your display scaling set to?  150%?

Comment: Thank you @genpfault , display scaling solved it. I wonder why 150% percent was indicated by the os as 'recommended'.